# Use different page sequence master for one document

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a document in which I need different page layouts. 
For example:

- the first 3-5 pages are simple-page-master "A"
- then comes a table of contents with a content where a distinction is made between even and odd pages: page-sequence-master "B".
- and finally 4-5 pages simple-page-master "C"

At the moment i only use one page-sequence-master in which i can use different simple-page-masters for the first page as well as for even and odd pages. however i need a different treatment from the beginning, main part, and end in the output PDF.

In my XML i have something like:

```
<!-- should be rendered to page layout "A" -->
<section>
  <layout>beginning</layout>
   ...
</section>

<!-- should be rendered to page layout "B" -->
<section>
  <layout>mainpart</layout>
   ...
</section>

<!-- should be rendered to page layout "C" -->
<section>
  <layout>end</layout>
   ...
</section>
```

The sections contain a lot of data like chapters paragraphs, pictures...
So finally it becomes a PDF with around 45 pages

My XSL looks like that:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="DIN-A4-ODD" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm"                    margin-top="1.5cm" margin-bottom="1.5cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="1.5cm">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="3.5cm" margin-bottom="1.5cm" margin-left="1cm" margin-                    right="1cm" />
                <fo:region-before region-name="ODD-header" extent="3.5cm" />
                <fo:region-after region-name="ODD-footer" extent="1.5cm" />
                <fo:region-start region-name="ODD-left" extent="1cm" />
                <fo:region-end region-name="ODD-right" extent="1cm" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="DIN-A4-EVEN" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm"                 margin-top="1.5cm"
                margin-bottom="1.5cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="1.5cm">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="3.5cm" margin-bottom="1.5cm" margin-left="1cm" 
                margin-right="1cm" />
                <fo:region-before region-name="EVEN-header" extent="3.5cm" />
                <fo:region-after region-name="EVEN-footer" extent="1.5cm" />
                <fo:region-start region-name="EVEN-left" extent="1cm" />
                <fo:region-end region-name="EVEN-right" extent="1cm" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="TITLEPAGE" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm"                   margin-top="1cm"
                margin-bottom="1cm" margin-left="1cm" margin-right="1cm">
                <fo:region-body />
                <fo:region-after region-name="TITLEPAGE-footer" extent="1cm" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
            <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="DIN-A4">
                <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="TITLEPAGE" 
                page-position="first"/>
                <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="DIN-A4-ODD" 
                    odd-or-even="odd" page-position="any" />
                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="DIN-A4-EVEN" 
                    odd-or-even="even" page-position="any" />
                </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            </fo:page-sequence-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="DIN-A4">
            <!-- TITLEPAGE-footer logo -->
            <fo:static-content flow-name="TITLEPAGE-footer">
                <fo:block text-align="right">
                    <fo:external-graphic src="url(file:C:Logo.pdf)" max-height="1cm" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <!-- ODD Header Content -->
            <fo:static-content flow-name="ODD-header">
                <fo:block text-align="right" font-size="8pt">
                    <fo:inline>
                        <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="HeadingSection" />
                    </fo:inline>
                    <fo:inline>
                        <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="HeadingChapter" />
                    </fo:inline>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:static-content flow-name="ODD-right">
                <fo:block text-align="right" font-size="8pt">
                    <fo:inline>
                        <fo:page-number />
                    </fo:inline>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <!-- EVEN Header Content -->
            <fo:static-content flow-name="EVEN-header">
                <fo:block text-align="left" font-size="8pt">
                    <fo:inline>
                        <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="HeadingSection" />
                    </fo:inline>
                    <fo:inline>
                        <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="HeadingChapter" />
                    </fo:inline>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:static-content flow-name="EVEN-left">
                <fo:block text-align="left" font-size="8pt">
                    <fo:inline>
                        <fo:page-number />
                    </fo:inline>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <!-- body declaration -->
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

As I said I have no idea how to get the dynamics I need and I hope that somebody can help me out with that.

Answer (score 1):

You create multiple fo:page-sequence-master's with different names. You have one in your example ... create as many as you need. Like for instance:

```
<fo:page-sequence-master master-name="DIN-A4-A"> ... definition here for your "A" pages
<fo:page-sequence-master master-name="DIN-A4-B"> ... definition here for your "B" pages
<fo:page-sequence-master master-name="DIN-A4-C"> ... definition here for your "C" pages
<fo:page-sequence-master master-name="DIN-A4-D"> ... definition here for your "D" pages
```

Then you output them in content through page-sequences referring to the sequence-masters you have defined:

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="DIN-A4-A"> ... stuff here for your "A" pages
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="DIN-A4-B"> ... stuff here for your "B" pages
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="DIN-A4-C"> ... stuff here for your "C" pages
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="DIN-A4-D"> ... stuff here for your "D" pages
```

In your page-sequence definitions you can refer different or even same simple-page-masters should some be shared/same. Each "chunk" of content representing a set of pages is your page-sequence, it refers to a page-sequence-master (or in fact can refer to a simple-page-master if it is not a sequence).